Is the group of isometries on $R^2$ the Euclidean group, $E(2)$?
I‘m looking for a proof that the group of isometries on $R^2$ is the Euclidean group, E(2). I know elements of the Euclidean group E(n) can be represented by pairs (A,x) where A is in the orthogonal group O(n) and x is in $R^n$. I guess I’m just not sure how to go from that pair to an isometry of the form $Ax + y$. Any help would be appreciated.

Yes, the isometry group of $\Bbb R^n$ is $E(n)=O_n(\Bbb R)\rtimes \Bbb R^n$.

I think a proof can be found here: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/classical/galilei_pro.pdf

@HughMann Well yes, he didn't prove that $(R,u)$  gives rise to an isometry $f$, just a map. But I think you can easily check this is an isometry.
